# Can I make CLion highlight doxygen comments differently than other comments?

Tags: comments, syntax-highlighting, doxygen, clion

I'm a new user of CLion (version 2020.2), writing C++ code.

CLion has some sort of Doxygen support - it's willing to "render" Doxygen and present the rendered comment in a side-pane. However, within the code itself, the Doxygen comments have the same font and color as regular comments.

I know that in Eclipse, the preferences has an option you can set which sets Doxygen comments to a different color. Is there something equivalent in CLion?

Note: A plugin would be fine; but I couldn't find a relevant one, searching for "Doxygen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr: Upgrade to CLion 2020.3 or better yet 2021.2 .

I have this running in version 2020.3:
[image: clion settings for doxygen]

They have also recently fixed a bug with this feature in version 2021.2 EAP.

You basically go to your Settings and go into Editor | Color Scheme | Language Default and there you'll find the "Comments | Doc Comment" section.

you can specify different colors for doxygen comments, and even different handling of different sections of your doxygen comments

Comment: Is 2020.3 the earliest version with this capability?

Comment: I don't know sorry... I have removed the older versions from my PC. Someone else might chime in on that one.